# How to lookup values in multidimensional tables with blank cells for row-titles?

Tags: excel, lookup

Okay, so my title is beyond confusing so let me explain through an image; this is an example of the data I received:

[image: Given Example]

I'm required to create a sheet where if the input is, for instance, **Category B**, **Sub-Cat. ii** and **Item 4**, a formula would grab the respective values for the respective dates, something like this:

[image: Result Example]

Anyone know whether or not it's possible to have a formula for the results in the second table without having to fill all the blanks in the given (or conducting any *merging*)? .. and if it is, how? I have been trying to figure this out for the past 3 hours with no avail.

I'm aware I can create a dummy sheet and use some formulas to fill the blank cell and from thereon use simple formulas to get the required results.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: So, you don't want to use another sheet with formulas, you do not refer [vba], you probably don't want to insert a formula in every blank space manually... What do you want???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your item numbers are unique, the sub category is irrelevant.  In which case, the following formula should work (*assuming the values are in* `A1:E12`):

**Get the category**

```
=MATCH("Category B",A1:A12,0)
```

**Get the Item in the category**

```
=MATCH("Item 4",OFFSET(C1:C6,MATCH("Category B",A1:A12,0)-1,0))
```

**Get the index of the date required**

```
=INDEX(D1:D12,MATCH("Category B",A1:A12,0)+
MATCH("Item 4",OFFSET(C1:C6,MATCH("Category B",A1:A12,0)-1,0))-1)
```

Obviously you can break this into multiple cells and hide a few, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to retrieve the name of the *medium black cat*.  This is *Cupid*.

We **could** use:

```
=INDEX(D2:D100,SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100="medium")*(B2:B100="black")*(C2:C100="cat")*ROW(2:100))-1)
```

**if** all the sizes, colors and animal types were filled in.

So we **cheat**.

We start with:

```
Size    Color   Animal  Name
large   black   bird    Margaret
large   black   cat     Trinculo
large   black   dog     Sycorax
large   brown   bird    Ferdinand
large   brown   cat     Prospero
large   brown   dog     Setebos
large   white   bird    Stephano
large   white   cat     Oberon
large   white   dog     Caliban
medium  black   bird    Francisco
medium  black   cat     Cupid
medium  black   dog     Miranda
medium  brown   bird    Titania
medium  brown   cat     Ariel
medium  brown   dog     Umbriel
medium  white   bird    Puck
medium  white   cat     Belinda
medium  white   dog     Perdita
small   black   bird    Juliet
small   black   cat     Cressida
small   black   dog     Desdemona
small   brown   bird    Mab
small   brown   cat     Portia
small   brown   dog     Rosalind
small   white   bird    Bianca
small   white   cat     Cordelia
small   white   dog     Ophelia
```

We click on **A3** and apply *Conditional Formatting* to it with the *FormulaIs* Option:

```
=A3=A2
```

and pick the font colour to match in cell colour.  We then copy this format to the entire data table.  This "hides" the appropriate catagory cells and gives us the correct **visual effect.**

Now the *INDEX()?SUMPRODUCT()* formula will work.